# How to send and read image/video in iOS message extension?

Tags: ios, video, imessage, msmessage

**My goal:**

- Allow user to send (or attach) a video clip to a message
- Allow receiver to read (not playing) the video when it is received
- Not using an additional server to host these messages or videos. In other words, I want everything to be done within the message extension framework.

**I tried:**

1) Using MSMessage:

```
private func insertVideoIntoMessage(usingUrl url: URL) {
    if let conversation = self.activeConversation {
        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()

        layout.caption = "Some caption"
        layout.mediaFileURL = url                // Media file (video)

        let message = MSMessage()
        message.layout = layout            
        message.url = URL(string: "some url")

        conversation.insert(message, completionHandler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error:", error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I would like to let the receiver read the media file (video). However, it doesn't seem to be possible.

```
override func didSelect(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) { 
    // message doesn't seem to contain any media content 
}
```

2) Using an attachment:

```
private func insertVideoInMessage(usingUrl url: URL) {
    if let conversation = self.activeConversation {
        conversation.insertAttachment(url, withAlternateFilename: "Some file name", completionHandler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error:", error)
            }
        })
}
```

This way the attachment (video) is opened by the system's default App. Which means my App couldn't read the video.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to let receiver read the video sent by sender?
- Is it possible to insert an attachment **AND** insert an MSMessage at the same time?
- Or is there any other way that I could do what I want?

Comment: did you find any solution?